# Nuget with devops and fallback

Tags: deployment, nuget, devops

Is it possible for a dev team to utlize nuget when the repository is available and fallback to an included assembly folder when the repository is not available?

E.G.  Our dev team has access to a nuget repository, so when we update our nuget packages from the repo that is not available to the deployment team, we would want to update the included assemblies with those assemblies...and allow the build/deployment team to fallback to the included assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared folder on your network as a backup repository.

Simply pick a shared folder that everyone, and the build server's user account, has access to.

Then, add a new package source pointing to this folder

[image]

Lastly, make sure that whenever you update a nuget package, you drop a copy of it in this backup folder.  A simple script could do this for you.